# Non required email validation in Flask WTForms

Tags: python, validation, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am using **wtforms** with **flask** and I have an input box for the email.
I want to **validate the email** entry but also have it as **non-required** field.
The user can ommit it, but if they enter it I want to make sure it passes the Email validator of wtforms.

Ideally, I would like to have something like this:

```
email = StringField('Email', validators=[Email(), DataNotRequired()])
```

or

```
email = StringField('Email', validators=[Email(required=False)])
```

I guess the only possible way to achieve this using Flask-WTforms, is to create a **custom** **validator**. In that case, is there a way to **utilize the Email() validator** in my custom validator, so I won't have to reimplement it ?

Something like that:

```
def validate_email(form, field):
    if len(field.data) > 0:
        if (not Email(field.data)):
            raise ValidationError('Email is invalid')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the validator "Optional" should solve the problem. "Optional" stops the evaluation chain if the data field contains no value or only whitespace, without raising an error:

```
email = StringField('Email', validators=[Optional(), Email()])
```

Comment: True :) `from wtforms.validators import Optional`

Answer (score 0):

A complete email validation form (login form)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired , Email , Length

class login_form(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label='Email *',validators=[DataRequired(),Email(message="Invalid Id , Check the Format")]  ) #Email()  can also be included
    password = PasswordField(label='Password *',validators=[Length(min=6 )  ])                                 # message="Atleast 6 characters "   can also be included
    submit = SubmitField(label="Log In")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).